# How do insert a custom "not found message" on my search function using Javascript in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been able to implement a search function using AJAX in Rails but when a user types in a search query and doesn't find anything the result currently displays nothing.  Instead of this, I want to display a message such as: 'Sorry nothing was found!', but I can't seem to get this to work.

This is my code from the `index.js.erb` file:

```
$('#products').append('<%= escape_javascript render(@products) %>');
$('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript paginate(@products) %>');
```

This is the code in my `index.html.erb` file:

```
<%= form_tag products_path, method: :get, authentication: false, id: 'search-form' do %>

    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>

<% end %>

<div class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-3" id="products">
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <%= render product %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And finally this is the bit of relevant code in my `products_controller.rb` file:

```
respond_to :html, :js, :json

def index
    @products = if params[:search].present?
      Product.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
    else
      Product.all
    end

    @products = Product.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(13)

    respond_with @products
  end

  def search
    @products = Product.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
    render @products
  end
```

Sorry I should've included this in the question as well.  Now I am able to get this message of "Sorry nothing was found!" message to display when a search query comes up with nothing, BUT the problem is that I have to press enter twice in order for it to display the message.  What can I do to change my code here so when nothing is found the first time it displays: "Sorry nothing was found!"?

This is the code in my `assets/javascripts/products.js` file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search-form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var searchValue = $('#search').val();

        $.get('/products/search?search='+searchValue)
            .done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if ($("#products").children().length != 0){
                $('#products').html(data);
            }else{
                $('#products').html("<h3>Sorry nothing was found!</h3>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I believe that's all the necessary information needed to understand this question.  If you need more clarification in order to understand what I'm doing, I'll be glad to provide it.

Thank you all for your input!

Comment: Is it ok that you assign `@products` twice in `index` action, and second time you overwrite whatever there was about search? maybe you meant to have `@products = @products.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(13)` ?

Comment: I changed the code above to make it more clear for what I want the @products variable to be, but I'm thinking the problem that I'm having is probably related to my index.js.erb filing not running the Javascript correctly.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't seem to get this to work"? Can you show us the Ajax response?

Comment: Change you made didn't change the fact that you overwrite `@products`

Comment: Any way, try inspecting index.js output directly in browser

Comment: @lobanovadik this line of: products = Product.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(13) is for paginating the index page where I'm using it for an infinite scroll feature

Comment: Well, how do you think search results can survive this pagination assignment?

Comment: @lobanovadik The pagination has nothing to do with with the search, I'm using AJAX to return the search results.  Take a look at the snippet of code I added in the assets/javascripts/products.js file